# Self-Signed Certificate private key values mismatch

Tags: python, apache, ssl, python-requests

I'm getting an error when i try to do a request on my webpage using a self-signed certificates.

This is how i create my self-signed Certificate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
#
day=300
server="domain.tld"
path_build="domain"
openssl_conf="openssl.cnf"
cd $path_build

# Create CA self-signed certificate
openssl req -config $openssl_conf -new -x509 -subj "/C=COUNTRY/L=Town/O=domain CA/CN=$server" -days $day -key private/rootCA.key -out certs/rootCA.crt
# Server Side
# Create private key for the domain server
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:qwerty -out private/${server}.key 2048
# Remove passphrase
openssl rsa -passin pass:qwerty -in private/${server}.key -out private/${server}.key

# Create CSR for the domain server
openssl req -config $openssl_conf -new -subj "/C=COUNTRY/L=Town/O=domain/CN=$server" -key private/${server}.key -out csr/${server}.csr
# Create certificate for the domain server
openssl ca -batch -config $openssl_conf -days $day -in csr/${server}.csr -out certs/${server}.crt -keyfile private/rootCA.key -cert certs/rootCA.crt -policy policy_anything
```

Then i create my client certificates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x
path_build="domain"
day=300
CN="client"
openssl_conf="openssl.cnf"

cd $path_build
# Create private key for a client
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:qwerty -out private/${CN}.key 2048

# Remove passphrase
openssl rsa -passin pass:qwerty -in private/${CN}.key -out private/${CN}.key

# Create CSR for the client.
openssl req -config $openssl_conf -new -subj "/C=COUNTRY/L=Town/O=domain/CN=$CN" -key private/${CN}.key -out csr/${CN}.csr

# Create client certificate.
openssl ca -batch -config $openssl_conf -days $day -in csr/${CN}.csr -out certs/${CN}.crt -keyfile private/rootCA.key -cert certs/rootCA.crt -policy policy_anything

# Export the client certificate to pkcs12 for import in the browser
openssl pkcs12 -export -passout pass:toto -in certs/${CN}.crt -inkey private/${CN}.key -certfile certs/rootCA.crt -out certs/${CN}cert.p12
```

So i endup with

```
ls domain/certs domain/private domain/csr
  domain/certs/:
    domain.crt client.crt clientcert.p12 rootCA.crt

  domain/csr:
    domain.csr client.csr

  domain/private/:
    domain.key client.key rootCA.key
```

I copy then the certificates for the serveur and the client:

Serveur Side:
cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAlias domain.tld
ServerName domain.tld

WSGIDaemonProcess daemon user=user group=group threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/current/apache/preprod.wsgi
WSGIPassAuthorization On
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /home/user/current/apache/certs/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user/current/apache/certs/domain.key

  <Directory /home/user/current/apache>
    Require all granted
      WSGIProcessGroup procsGroup
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then on the client side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()

_certfile = "certs/rootCA.crt"
_private_key = "certs/client.key"
_client_cert = "certs/client.crt"
username="user"
password="pass"
url='https://domain.tld/api/1.0/bob/create'

r =  requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), params={}, verify=_client_cert, cert=(_certfile, _private_key))
```

And i got as an answer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codes_generation.py", line 167, in <module>
    print(request(""))
  File "codes_generation.py", line 74, in request
    r =  requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), params=order, verify=_client_cert, cert=(_certfile, _private_key))
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 107, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 784, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 252, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 277, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ctx.use_privatekey_file(keyfile)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 665, in use_privatekey_file
    self._raise_passphrase_exception()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 640, in _raise_passphrase_exception
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/mailchimp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_check_private_key', 'key values mismatch')]
```

When i try to access in my browser i got an alert for a self-signed certificates (which is normal and fine) but when i try to use the request library in python it doesn't work. (using python 2.7)

I'm not good at all with certificates, and i thinks i probably just put the wrong file at the wrong place, because i don't really get what file is for what used.

So i'm trying to understand how self-signed certificates work and where is my problem. If you have any ressources on that, every linked i've been browsing about self-signed certificate is rarely very clear.

Answer (score 0):

So i've found where is was wrong, i was using the wrong file:

```
_certfile = "certs/domain.crt"
_private_key = "certs/domain.key"
_client_cert = "certs/rootCA.crt"
```

And this work

```
_certfile = "certs/client.crt"
_private_key = "certs/client.key"
_client_cert = "certs/rootCA.crt"
```

But i still don't understand certificates, i got that it's used by pair, but why the domain files and the client files are working for the client ?

So if you have any documentation clear enough i would be glad !

Thanks everyone